# can caching information attached to image file names cause a 404 error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I deployed a Rails app successfully, however, the images are not displaying. This is the 404 error that's showing in the console

```
GET http://mydomain.com/assets/myimage.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Inside my application directory on my server, there's three subdirectories

```
current  releases  shared
```

which is a setup created by the deployment script I borrowed from Ryan Bates.

I can see the images in the images directory of the assets folder in `current`

```
  current/app/assets/images$ ls
glyphicons-halflings.png  glyphicons-halflings-white.png  qb.png
```

However, in the assets folder of the `shared` directory (which is I'm guessing where they're being put after everything's compiled for production), the same images have some (I'm assuming) cache information attached to them, such that the image I want isn't

```
myimage.png
```

but rather

```
myimage-0bb3f134943971c95b2abdfd30f932c7.png
```

I'm wondering if this is what's causing the 404 error, as (I'm assuming) the code's looking for myimage.png in the shared/assets directory.

Do you know how I can deal with this problem?

contents of `/shared/assets`

```
/shared/assets$ ls
application-39c95ed7b8d86b0698b6c443563e33c7.js           fontawesome-webfont-c4adb9424c8b6a6b1b9b0d2627528c4c.woff
application-39c95ed7b8d86b0698b6c443563e33c7.js.gz        fontawesome-webfont-f57557847fd1897100790d9df344ded8.ttf
application-7a6376d676fb88537b9f839687ccaad3.css          glyphicons-halflings-4e5b89324f1ac987ddf6835ef51f5fe9.png
application-7a6376d676fb88537b9f839687ccaad3.css.gz       glyphicons-halflings-white-2fa53df59ca25ee50f59f971c0c9175d.png
application-a184171300937caf263adbc5e8582ba4.css          manifest-990c8a24196fee5e9c394078c326c763.json
application-a184171300937caf263adbc5e8582ba4.css.gz       myimage-0bb3f134943971c95b2abdfd30f932c7.png
fontawesome-webfont-57b442a30fcae0d4334299c521a326a2.svg  twitter
fontawesome-webfont-8140ac47a16c8f7074e59f2ebe0657eb.eot
```

code used to display images

1. For one image, I create a span like this

and then assign it a background image

```
.qb{
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-image: url('/assets/qb.png');
left: 75px;
top: 300px;

}
```

For another image, I have a template like this with a class that automatically uses Twitter bootstrap to create a `x` to let uses click and remove a page element

```
<script id="blahblah_template" type="text/underscore">
<h2> The Story <i class='icon-remove'></i></h2>
```

It's triggering a 404 even though the image is on the server

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 

    http://mydomain.com/assets/glyphicons-halflings.png
```

Comment: What is the code you're using to display the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use asset helpers provided by rails which would automagically create the right url to the image with caching build in. here is how:

```
.qb{
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-image: url( <%= asset_path 'qb.png' %> ); 
left: 75px;
top: 300px;

}
```

the above will map `qb.png` to `qb-0bb3f134943971c95b2abdfd30f932c7.png` & also update the url once the caching fingerprint changes. just make sure that your stylesheet filename has `.erb` at the end, something like `stylesheet.css.erb`

see [The Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets) guide for more information

**[edit]**

For Bootstrap integration with rails asset pipeline, kindly use gem like [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass). it will fix your issues with images

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution works for images used as background images in css styles I create,  but I don't see how to do that for the Twitter Bootstrap glyphicons-halflings.png, which is attached to the class `<i class='icon-remove'>`.  I tried to do this in a css file `.icon-remove{
  background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'glyphicons-halflings.png' %>);
}` but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: you can use twitter bootstrap gem & fix this. I have updated my answer with more information